# mysql_num_rows gives boolean error

Tags: authentication, boolean, rows

I'm working on a login script currently and I'm trying to get comfortable with query's and all those things around it. I'm getting it slightly, but the code below, which checks the username & password when people want to login, doesn't quite work. I get an error:

**Warning**: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in **C:\xampp\htdocs\mystagram\logic\login_validate.php** on line **13**

```
<?php

include('../includes/config.php');
include('../includes/database.php');

$username = mysql_escape_string($_POST['username']);
$password = mysql_escape_string($_POST['password']);
$submit = $_POST['submit_login'];

if (isset($submit)) {

    $loginquery = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'");
        if (mysql_num_rows($loginquery) > 0) {
            echo 'You are now logged in.';
            exit();
        } else {
            echo 'Wrong username or password.';
        }


}

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

This means that you have an error in your SQL Statement.

Probably you dont have a table named 'users' or the Column 'username' or 'password' is missing.

Change this:

```
if (mysql_num_rows($loginquery) > 0) {
```

To:

```
if (mysql_num_rows($loginquery) == 1) {
```

And don't save your password in plaintext in the database. And use mysqli :)

Comment: Can you explain the useage of mysqli? I hear a lot of people talking about it, but I don't get it.. ;/

Comment: and btw, I still got the error. I checked it twice and the tables are good either...

Comment: Maybe you forgot to select the right database? Please provide the whole src in a zip file, then i will check it for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
you use mysql_escape_string() then '' it was problem. try this code,I hope it will work.

<?php

    include('../includes/config.php');
    include('../includes/database.php');

    $username = mysql_escape_string($_POST['username']);
    $password = mysql_escape_string($_POST['password']);
    $submit = $_POST['submit_login'];

    if (isset($submit)) {

        **$loginquery = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username=".$username." AND password=".$password);**
            if (mysql_num_rows($loginquery) > 0) {
                echo 'You are now logged in.';
                exit();
            } else {
                echo 'Wrong username or password.';
            }


    }

    ?>
```

Comment: so may be your query not return in boolean value.your password is use any encryption.if you the password should be decode like md5($password) ...I test it my localhost it work .. so please check query or just mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username=".$username)

Comment: Okay so I changed mysql_query to mysqli_query and mysql_num_rows to mysqli_num_rows, but now I got this error:



**Warning**: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in **C:\xampp\htdocs\mystagram\logic\login_validate.php** on line **12**

**Warning**: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in **C:\xampp\htdocs\mystagram\logic\login_validate.php** on line **13**

Comment: if have any encryption in password

Comment: $loginquery = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE ");
        if (mysql_num_rows($loginquery) > 0) {
            echo 'You are now logged in.';
            exit();
        } else {
            echo 'Wrong username or password.';
        }


}

?>just try using this query only

Comment: you send me your full project with database in zip i will correct it and send you